# Code property on NpgsqlException

Tags: npgsql

I'm trying to move from v2.0.11 of NPGSQL to v3.1.7 howeer in my code I am accessing the Code property of NpgsqlException.  In 3.1.7 this has gone; how can I access the underlying code error from postgres now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Npgsql 3.1, PostgreSQL errors are thrown as PostgresException, not NpgsqlException (which is reserved for other errors, e.g. network issues). If you catch PostgresException, you'll find the `SqlState` property which has replaced `Code` (which still exists but is obsoleted).